# Javascript - How to loop through each word and push them to an empty array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate a random words and push each one individually to the array, the problem is, i am getting list of words that starts from the first letter increased by one like this:

['a','ab','abc','abcd'] and so on

here is my code:

```
var word = "";
var texts = [];
var letters = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    word += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length))
    texts.push(
        {
            "id":i,
            "name":word,
            selected: false
        }
    )
}
```

what i need is to push a complete word to the list.

Comment: To do it like this you will need two loops: one from `0 to numWords` and inside that  one from `0 to numLetters`.

Comment: For the first time i did it with two loops, but my browser got freezed!! i think i did it the wrong way but thank you @MarkMeyer for your interest :)

Comment: Russian w/ a handle about a hacking movie, asking for help in generating random words… what's your purpose?

Comment: @vol7ron its not what you are thinking about, its just a small app that i am creating using `Flask` and `VueJS` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var texts = [];
var letters = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
var wordLength = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    let word = "";
    for(var j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
      word += letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length));
    }
    texts.push(
        {
            "id": i,
            "name": word,
            selected: false
        }
    )
}
```

You need to use another one loop for generate a words. New word's loop each time.

Comment: I am glad to help you.
P.S. Last time (when your "browser got freezed") might have been infinity loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var word = "";
var texts = [];
var letters = "abcdefghijklmn";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    word = letters.slice(1,i)
    texts.push(word);
}
alert(texts);
```

Oh, sorry you need it random;
how about this

```
var word = "";
var texts = [];
var letters = "abcdefghijklmn";
var l = letters.length;
var textsNum = 10;
for (var v = 0; v < textsNum; v++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    word += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * l)];
  }
  texts.push(word);
  word = '';
}

console.dir(texts);
```

Comment: You see , the result is the same as my code, but thanks for your interest :)